# how to override method which returns <T extends SomeClass> T

Tags: java

I have a protected abstract method in ClassA:

```
protected abstract <T extends Class1> T methodName();
```

When I override this method in subclass ClassB, I keep getting the type safety warning: The return type Class2 for methodName() from the type ClassB needs unchecked conversion to conform to T from the type ClassA.
Here, Class2 extends Class1

How could I get ride of this warning without using @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Comment: Show the original `ClassA` code and your own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How could I get ride of this warning without using @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Only by doing it a different way. What you are doing is inherently unsafe. From the compiler message, we can deduce that what you have is something like this:

```
class Class1 {}
class Class2 extends Class1 {}

abstract class ClassA {
    protected abstract <T extends Class1> T methodName();
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {
    @Override
    protected Class2 methodName() {
        return new Class2();
    }
}
```

This is allowed because of a weird interaction with erasure, the erasure of `<T extends Class1>` is `Class1` so overriding to return a concrete subtype is allowed. (It is 'override equivalent'.)

It is unsafe because the return type of `methodName` in `ClassA` is generic and therefore determined by the caller. It can be `Class1` or any subtype of `Class1`. This will cause a ClassCastException:

```
class Class3 extends Class1 {}

ClassA actuallyB = new ClassB();
Class3 c3 = actuallyB.<Class3>methodName();
```

It results in a `Class2` being casted to a `Class3`.

Instead, you can declare that return type as being a parameter to the class (this has already been suggested):

```
abstract class ClassA<T extends Class1> {
    protected abstract T methodName();
}
```

Or simply not use generics:

```
abstract class ClassA {
    protected abstract Class1 methodName();
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {
    @Override
    protected Class2 methodName() {
        return new Class2();
    }
}
```

(Java lets you override to return a subtype, if you did not know that.) And in general you should not use generics unless you really need them.

Answer (score 0):

That type of method in `ClassA` means that you can call `methodName()` for *any* `T` that extends `Class1`.  That means you can't override it to return *some specific* `T` that extends `Class1`.

Instead, you'll have to make `T` a type parameter of the class:

```
abstract class ClassA<T extends Class1> {
   protected abstract T methodName();
}
class ClassB extends ClassA<Class2> {
   @Override protected Class2 methodName() {...}
}
```

Comment: No, that exists, it just doesn't do what you want it to.

Comment: But if you mean for subclasses to be able to return a specific subtype of `Class1` that doesn't have to be named as a generic parameter, then all you need to write is `protected abstract Class1 methodName()`, and override it to return the subtype.

Comment: I don't really understand what this type of method means. could you explain more. thx

Comment: Which type of method are you asking about?  `protected abstract <T extends Class1> T methodName()` means that if you have an instance of `ClassA`, or any of its subclasses, that you could call `myClassA.<Class2>methodName()`, or `myClassA.<Class3>methodName()`, or generally call `methodName()` for _any_ subtype of `Class1`.  It sounds like what you want is to have subclasses of `ClassA` return a specific subtype of `Class1`, rather than being able to return any subtype of `Class1`.

Comment: yeah, you have already solved my problem with the 2nd comment. With last comment, I was just curious what `protected abstract <T extends Class1> T methodName()` means. And does `myClassA.<Class2>methodName()` in your last comment return Class2?

Comment: It would, yes.  It is like saying "Set `T` to `Class2` in this invocation."

Comment: thx for your answer. And I am really sorry that I accepted the another answer, because he include enough code to explain the issue and I think you would help others to understand this easier. I really want to accept both of your answers. But, again, I am really sorry.